# Searching through multiple table using laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to implement an advanced searching option in my website using Laravel. Searching through 3 to 4 table to get the desired result.
I wrote db query and I'm getting desired result as output but I need to convert this to eloquent, and I've written some of it, but not getting the desired result as db query does. Any idea how to achieve it?

DB query

```
$product = DB::table('products')
->select(['products.id', 'products.title','package.name','products.product_summary','products.description'
    ,'package.description'
    ,'products.min_price','products.rating_count'])
->leftjoin('package',function($q){
    $q->on('products.package_id' ,'package.id');
})
->leftjoin('package_packagecategories',function($q){
    $q->on('package.id','package_packagecategories.package_id');
})
->leftjoin('product_categories',function($q){
    $q->on('package_packagecategories.category_id','product_categories.id');
})
->leftjoin('country',function($q){
    $q->on('products.country','country.id');
})
->where('products.status',1)
->Where('products.title','like',"%{$string}%")
->orWhere('products.product_summary', 'like', "%{$string}%")
->orWhere('products.description', 'like', "%{$string}%")
->orWhere('package.name', 'like', "%{$string}%")
->orWhere('package.description', 'like', "%{$string}%")
->orWhere('package.product_summary', 'like', "%{$string}%")
->orWhere('country.name', 'like', "%{$string}%")
->get();
```

and the eloquent written so far for the above db query

```
Product::select('id', 'title','product_summary','description','min_price','rating_count')
                    ->WhereHas('Package',function($q)use($string){
                        $q->orWhere(DB::raw('LOWER(name->>"$.en")'),'like',"%{$string}%")
                        ->orWhere(DB::raw('LOWER(description->>"$.en")'),'like',"%{$string}%")
                        ->orWhere(DB::raw('LOWER(product_summary->>"$.en")'),'like',"%{$string}%")
                        ->orWhereHas('categories',function($subq)use($string){
                            $subq->orWhere(DB::raw('LOWER(name->>"$.en")'),'like',"%{$string}%");
                        });
                    })
                    ->WhereHas('country',function($q)use($string){
                        $q->orWhere('name','like',"%{$string}%");
                    })
```

I need to get the result for second code as db query do.

Comment: In my opinion, when you make a search functionality, a lot of processing is required. When you use query builder queries and some raw queries to make a search functionality it will be faster than the eloquent query if you have large database. If you explain the reason behind converting to eloquent query then it would be better.

Comment: I have media library relation with product model , so fetching  its content can only done through eloquent , i guess so.

Answer (score 2):

Finally abled to figured out a working code ..

```
$product->where(function($p)use($string){$p->orWhereHas('country',function($q)use($string){
                                $q->where('name','like',"%".strtolower($string)."%");
                            })
                            ->orWhere( DB::raw('LOWER(products.title)'),'like',"%".strtolower($string)."%")
                            ->orWhere(DB::raw('LOWER(products.product_summary)'),'like',"%".strtolower($string)."%")
                            ->orWhere(DB::raw('LOWER(products.description)'),'like',"%".strtolower($string)."%")
                            ->orWhereHas('categories',function($subq)use($string){
                                $subq->where(DB::raw('LOWER(name)'),'like',"%".strtolower($string)."%");
                            })
                            ->orWhereHas('Package',function($subq)use($string){
                                $subq->where(DB::raw('LOWER(name)'),'like',"%".strtolower($string)."%");
                            })
                            ->orWhereHas('Package',function($subq)use($string){
                                $subq->where(DB::raw('LOWER(description)'),'like',"%".strtolower($string)."%");
                            })
                            ->orWhereHas('Package',function($subq)use($string){
                                $subq->where(DB::raw('LOWER(product_summary)'),'like',"%".strtolower($string)."%");
                            })
                            ->orWhereHas('Package',function($subq)use($string){
                                $subq->whereHas('categories',function($subq)use($string){
                                    $subq->where(DB::raw('LOWER(name)'),'like',"%".strtolower($string)."%");
                                });
                            })
                            ->orWhereHas('Package',function($subq)use($string){
                                $subq->whereHas('country',function($q)use($string){
                                    $q->where('country.name','like',"%".strtolower($string)."%");
                                });
                            });
                        });
```